Why does SQL-Server Management Studio change "Execute Query" into "Save Results"?
I'm a regular user of SQL-Server Management Studio but now I have a totally weird situation: when I press F5 or when I click on "Execute", SQL-Server Management Studio does not execute my query. Instead of this it opens the "Save Results" dialogue, as you can see:

Has anybody ever seen this and do you know how to handle this?
Thanks in advance

It seems you have accidentally asked SSMS to save your results to a file:

Reset it to "Results to Grid" or "Results to Text" as you prefer.
